# How can I reset my auto-incremented build number with every new version?

Tags: xcode, travis-ci

I've done a lot of Googling and read a lot of threads here on SO but can't find an answer to this one.

I work on a small iOS development team and we have our repo on Github using Travis CI for our builds. I have auto incrementing set up for the build number which simply replaces the `CFBundleVersion` (build number) in Info.plist with the Travis build number every time it builds:

-- update-bundle.sh

```
if [ ! -z "$INFO_PLIST" ]; then
  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER" "$INFO_PLIST"
  echo "Set CFBundleVersion to $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
fi
```

-- and in travis.yml

```
env:
  global:
    - INFO_PLIST="OurAppName/app/support/Info.plist
    - <lots of other properties>
```

But I want to reset the `CFBundleVersion` and start the count at 1 whenever the `CFBundleShortVersionString` (version number) changes. For example:

My version is 2.0.3 and the build number is 47. When I change my version to 2.1.0 I want the build number of the 1st build for this version to be 1 and then increment as usual until the version changes again.

Is there a way to do this with with or without Travis?